# POST request using ASIHTTPRequest doesn't reach PHP script

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

I've got an iPhone app sending data to my server with a post request:

```
-(void) sendDataToServer:(NSString*)myString {
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://site.com/script.php"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Name" value:myString];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

}

But when I try

```
$blah = $_POST['Name'];
$fp = fopen('test.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $blah);
fclose($fp);
```

A blank line gets written, meaning the variable doesn't exist.
If i set it to write any old string it works, meaning them request is getting through, just not the data it carries.

The `myString` variable does have a value too, I checked in the debugger, so I'm not sending an empty string.

Comment: Hi I know this is an old question, but I am just starting PHP and have a quick question. Inside the php script, how do I send the value of myString to a web server, like http://mysite/myfile.txt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting a Header, but want you want is

```
[request appendPostData:[@"This is my data" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

or:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: Yeah, ASIHTTPRequest is awesome :)

Comment: Hah yeah, I looked at the Apple docs for NSURLRequest and the CFNetwork stuff and I was like "There will be a wrapper for all this that lets me do it in a  few lines" Looked around, and what do you know? (:

Comment: I tried to get along with the CFNetwork-Stuff one day. Since than I use either ASIHTTPRequest, AsyncSocket or cocoahttpserver.